# Finding integers $N$ and $M$ such that $|N\alpha-M-x|<\epsilon$.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

> Given an irrational number $\alpha$ and a real number $x$, show that for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exist integers $N$ and $M$ such that $|N\alpha-M-x|<\epsilon$.

I am stuck on this. I have tried approximating $\alpha$ with rational numbers but that doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere. Any hints? Is there a theorem that covers this?

Comment: To me, you can always fine tune x to make the left hand side fit between zero and however small you choose to make epsilon.

Comment: @PhilH $x$ is given.

Comment: This is known as [Kronecker's Approximation Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/KroneckersApproximationTheorem.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $G:=\alpha\Bbb Z+\Bbb Z$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb R$. 
Let $a=\inf\bigl(G\cap(0,\infty)\bigr)$.
Clearly, $0\le a\le 1$ . If $a>0$, then $G=a\Bbb Z$ and that would imply $\alpha\in\Bbb Q$.
We conclude that $a=0$.
Hence there exist $n,m\in\Bbb Z$ such that $0<n\alpha-m<2\epsilon$. Then a suitable multiple $kn\alpha-km$ will hit the interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.